# PostgreSQL update slow

Tags: postgresql, optimization, sql-update, sql-optimization

My update query takes days to run, and seems to get longer exponentially in production; I'm hoping that it can run faster. First, my query looks like this:

```sql
UPDATE table_1 a
SET boolean_column = TRUE
WHERE a.boolean_column = FALSE
AND EXISTS(SELECT b.joining_key
         FROM table_2 b
         WHERE a.primary_key = b.joining_key
           AND b.category = 'abc');
```

execution plan:

```
Update on table_1 a (cost=0.00..1137712.90 rows=1 width=136)
-> Nested Loop Semi Join (cost=0.00..1137712.90 rows=1 width=136)
Join Filter: (a.primary_key = (b.joining_key)::text)
-> Seq Scan on table_1 a (cost=0.00..36152.13 rows=1 width=129)
Filter: (NOT boolean_column)
-> Seq Scan on table_2 b (cost=0.00..1091459.31 rows=808117 width=33)
Filter: ((category)::text = 'abc'::text)
```

`table_1` has ~450K rows, and `table_2` has ~4.5 million rows, ~800K of which are `category = 'abc'`

Strange thing is, when I run the same query for different category, it only takes ~15 minutes:

```sql
UPDATE table_1 a
SET boolean_column = TRUE
WHERE a.boolean_column = FALSE
AND EXISTS(SELECT b.joining_key
         FROM table_2 b
         WHERE a.primary_key = b.joining_key
           AND b.category = 'bcd');
```

execution plan:

```
Update on table_1 a (cost=0.00..1154676.35 rows=1 width=136)
-> Nested Loop Semi Join (cost=0.00..1154676.35 rows=1 width=136)
Join Filter: (a.primary_key = (b.joining_key)::text)
-> Seq Scan on table_1 a (cost=0.00..36152.13 rows=1 width=129)
Filter: (NOT boolean_column)
-> Seq Scan on table_2 b (cost=0.00..1091533.00 rows=2159298 width=33)
Filter: ((category)::text = 'bcd'::text)
```

And in this case, `table_2` has ~2 million rows with `category = 'bcd'`

I don't know if it's related but I looked at some stats for `table_2` and see a large number dead tuples:

```sql
SELECT schemaname, relname, n_live_tup, n_dead_tup, last_autovacuum
FROM pg_stat_all_tables
WHERE relname = 'table_2'
ORDER BY n_dead_tup
             / (n_live_tup
                    * current_setting('autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor')::float8
        + current_setting('autovacuum_vacuum_threshold')::float8)
        DESC;

/* returns
schemaname  relname  n_live_tup     n_dead_tup  last_autovacuum
public      table_2  4363942        549768      2021-11-09 03:15:53.936604+00:00
*/
```

Would running `vacuum` in this case help? Although I am skeptical because again, other categories seem to run fine. I can provide additional information - thanks.

EDIT 1: `table_1` only has one constraint which is `table_1.primary_key` while `table_2` has only one constraint which is `table_2.primary_key`. currently, `table_2.joining_key` does not have a foreign key constraint associated with `table_1.primary_key`. would it help to add that constraint?

Comment: `where .. exists` is a very expensive pattern. Think of it as a nested loop where, for every one of the 450K records in `table`, the `exists` runs another query. If you have heard of the N+1 problem, this is it, and N is 450K. I'd recommend doing a join instead (`update .. from`, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-update.html)

Comment: @JaredBeck Not true! PostgreSQL will convert `EXISTS` into a semi join, which is efficient. With the correct indexes and enough resources, it should be efficient. But without knowing the definitions and the execution plan, it is hard to answer.

Comment: What is the execution plan for each query?  (Get that by running the query with EXPLAIN in front)

Comment: @jjanes i've just edited to add the execution plan for each query

Comment: Looks like the `Seq Scan on table_2` is the most expensive part of the plan. Try adding an index?

Comment:  Re: automatic conversion of `exists` into a join, that's really cool, thanks Laurenz!